# JSF h:inputTextarea to HTML textArea - passing maxlength attribute

Tags: jsf, richfaces, textarea, maxlength

I am using Richfaces and I am trying to make an `<textArea>` with maxlength atrribute set but JSF seems not to pass the maxlength attribute from h:inputTextArea. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<h:inputTextarea maxlength="100" cols="20" rows="10" value="#{bean.description}" id="description" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`maxlength` doesn't exists on `h:inputTextarea` ([see doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/inputTextarea.html)).

To add a validator message, try

```
<h:inputTextarea >
  <f:validateLength maximum="100"></f:validateLength>
</h:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: Ok so is there any way to pass such an atrribute? I tried <f:attribute >but that did not work. I have a javascript function that disallows entering more than "maxlength" characters in the textArea

Comment: Using javascript, you can try something like `<h:inputTextarea onkeyup="return checkMaxLength(this.value.length, 100);">` with `function checkMaxLength(length, maxLength){return length<=maxLength;}`.
 Be careful, I haven't try this code, but follow the idea...

Answer (score 1):

Our solution was to put an extra span immediately in front of the textarea that contained the maxlength number.

```
<span class="maxlength">35</span>
```

You give that class a "display: none;" rule to hide it. Then you use JavaScript to find each span.maxlength and move the number inside of it into the maxlength attribute of the textarea (using jQuery):

```
$('span.maxlength').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.next('textarea').attr('maxlength',$this.html());
    $this.remove();
});
```

Once that's done, run your other JavaScript that limits typing in textareas.

Hacky? Yes. But JSF not supporting maxlength is hacky.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a RichFaces issue but concerns JSF. 
It's also been answered better before. see @BalusC 's answer
[How to set maxlength attribute on h:inputTextarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923573/jsf-2-0-limit-length-for-hinputtextarea)