# How to set Inputtextarea attributes to display maximum length, rows and width

Tags: html, jsf-2

I set up this html code in jsf and it doesnt limit the length of characters, it still     go beyond 576 characters how do I set it up?  I need to set up the rows to 4 but opted to do style to be consistent on all browsers, is this correct?  Here is the code.

```
<td colspan="7">
 <h:outputText id="explanation1"
    value="#{handler.document.header.docDesc}"
rendered="#{documentHandler.mode != 2}"/>
 <h:inputTextarea id="explanation2" 
    value="#{documentHandler.document.header.docDesc}"
rendered="#{documentHandler.mode == 2}" 
style="height: 60px; width: 705px;"> 
    <f:validateLength maximum="576"/> 
</h:inputTextarea>   
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as you're writing some **JSF**, I suggest you also migrating the HTML table and convert it into a [`h:dataTable`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html). Appart from that, `<f:validateLength maximum="576"/>` tag is doing **JSF validation**, which is only done in server side. That means you're not limiting the client (browser) on typing, you perform validation only when form is sent and it's all done in server side.

To do that in client, you have to go to a Javascript/JQuery solution. Remember to assign the `textArea` an `styleClass` called `max`:

```
$('textarea.max').keyup(function() {
var $textarea = $(this);
var max = 576;
if ($textarea.val().length > max) {
    $textarea.val($textarea.val().substr(0, max));
}
});
```

[Original link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924933/1199132)

Comment: Can client side validation be done using ajax?  How do you do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Im using jsf and richfaces for this application.

Comment: I was looking for something like this.

Comment: I know, just click the tick on the left of my answer.  thanks

Comment: I cannot vote up, because I need 15 reputation, Im new and I only have 1.  Sorry.

Comment: There's a tick below the votes. It's disabled. Click on it and it will be green.