# Automatically set h:inputText maxlength based on Bean Validation @Size

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I use JSF 2 and Hibernate Validator 5.1 in a web application.

I use the annotations like `@Size` or `@NotNull` in my beans to validate automatically my HTML forms.

It works perfectly but I would like to know if there is a way to automatically limit the number of characters typed in an input text (ie set the attribute maxlength in HTML) based on the `@Size` annotation.

Comment: Do you have to use HibernateValidator anyway? `@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length(min = 5, max = 25, message = "Error message")` should go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried your solution but i have the same behaviour with the @Length annotation : it is possible to set more than 25 chars in my input (the input maxlength attribute is not set...) and the error message is displayed.

Comment: If more than 25 characters are attempted and the validation error message is displayed upon submission, then it is considered working.

Comment: I gathered that you want to delimit the number of characters in an input text as done by the `maxlength` HTML attribute. Go with `maxLength` (or use client script) which is always exploitable and should never be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Use [maxlength](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/inputText.html) attribute of <h:inputText>

You can also use f:validate -

```
<h:inputText id="Username" value="#{model.username}" 
                 required="true"
                label="UserName" >
                <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="10" />
            </h:inputText>
```

Answer (score -2):

**HTML5 + JSF 2.2+**

If you're using HTML5 and JSF 2.2+, specify it as a [passthrough attribute](http://jsfcorner.blogspot.pt/2013/06/jsf-22-pass-through-attributes.html).

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:inputTextarea value="#{bean.text}" a:maxlength="2000" />
```

Comment: A fat downvote for disrespectful [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923573/how-to-set-maxlength-attribute-on-hinputtextarea/4924933#4924933).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am looking for a way to specify automatically this attribute by using the hibernate validator @Size annotation.